# User able to modify file owned by root. Why?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I want to prevent a user from modifying a file but I can't seem to get it to work using standard permissions.

The file is `file.jpg`, which is in the folder `2012/`.

File details:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 10294 Feb 19  2013 file.jpg
```

Folder details:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 charly charly 36864 Aug 27 15:38 2012/
```

My intention is to prevent the user from renaming the file but with the permissions as they are he's able to.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the user in any privileged `groups`? Also, this question may be better for SuperUser or even ServerFault.

Comment: No, the user is a simple user.  The user can't rename or modify files in directories owned by root.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent renaming the file? Modifying a file means modifying some data (or meta data) in it (in its inode). **Why do you ask?**

Comment: The file has a trojan in it, so I renamed it to file.jpg.trojan and I want to make sure it can't be renamed back to file.jpg because the website got blacklisted because of it.  Of course I could just delete the file or trust the website developer won't rename it back to jpg, but I was wondering how to accomplish this.

Comment: Who owns the **directory**? The file permissions control who can access or change the contents, not who can change the name.

Comment: Mind, this is off-topic here altogether; it should be over on [unix.se].-

Answer (score 5):

You don't change a file when renaming it or moving it in the same filesystem, because a file is really an [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (which may have zero, one or more filenames in directories).

Renaming a file is an operation inside the relevant directories (not on the file itself). Perhaps removing write access to the directory might help (but if the user owns the directory, he could change again these permissions on the directory with `chmod`). Read also more about [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on directories.

BTW, the user could also hard link that same file, i.e. add a new filename to it. Then each filename is refering to the same file.

Comment: Thank you. And how would you accomplish this without removing the write permission on the directory for the user (since the user needs to add or modify other files)?  Is there any way you can think of?

Answer (score 2):

The permissions on a file prevent/allow access to the *file*. Renaming a file does not involve changing the file itself - renaming is actually a change to the *directory*.

Try changing the directory permissions to:

```
dr-xr-xr-x
```

and see what happens.